# What is the difference between a "unit" quaternion and an "identity" quaternion?

Tags: 3d, rotation

I have been using the guide at www.opengl-tutorial.org/intermediate-tutorials/tutorial-17-quaternions/ for learning OpenGL. This guide says that...

> glm::quat q;
>
> ...creates an identity quaternion (no rotation).

Experimentation shows that q = [0, 0, 0, 0]. Using this as the parent orientation of the root bone causes none of the bones to rotate at all. They lose all rotation.

The guide says that...

> A quaternion is a set of 4 numbers, [x y z w], which represents rotations the following way:
>
> // RotationAngle is in radians
>
> x = RotationAxis.x * sin(RotationAngle / 2)
>
> y = RotationAxis.y * sin(RotationAngle / 2)
>
> z = RotationAxis.z * sin(RotationAngle / 2)
>
> w = cos(RotationAngle / 2)

... and ...

> [0 0 0 1] (w=1) means that angle = 2*acos(1) = 0, so this is a unit quaternion, which makes no rotation at all.

I have been experimenting with a skeleton system where each bone inherits its parents' orientation before applying its own rotations on top of that.

If I use an "identity" quaternion as the "parent" orientation for the root bone, then none of the bones are rotated at all. If I use the "unit" rotation all is well.

When I set a bone's initial orientation to either the "identity" or "unit" quaternion it displays as I want to. However when I convert user entered Euler angles to an orientation I get a 180 degree rotation. The conversion I did was:

```
        glm::vec3 eulers(glm::radians(pose.lng_rotate),
                         glm::radians(pose.lat_rotate),
                         glm::radians(pose.att_rotate));

        pose.orientation = glm::quat(eulers);
```

Note: I use "lng", "lat", and "att" rotate here because by the time a bone has inherited a parent rotation the "x" axis is probably no longer the "x" axis any more.

The last weird thing I noticed was that I used `glm::mat4_cast` on each type of quaternion and then multiplied by an identity `glm::vec4`. The "identity" quaternion left the vector unrotated, but the "unit" quaternion caused the vector to invert (multiply by -1) the x and y components of the vector.

I want to understand quaternions better, especially with respect to their use in code.

**Conceptually, how is a "unit" quaternion different to an "identity" quaternion?**

**Where should I use a "unit" quaternion and where should I use an "identity" quaternion?**

**Am I just being confused by a badly written guide?**

Comment: "*Experimentation shows that q = [0, 0, 0, 0].*" Prove it. A quaternion of all zeros is not "an identity quaternion". I don't think GLM is that badly coded to have such a mistake.

Comment: @Nicol I simply did
`glm::quat q; printf("%s, %s, %s, %s\n", std::to_string(q.x).c_str(), std::to_string(q.y).c_str(), std::to_string(q.z).c_str(), std::to_string(q.w).c_str());`
The reason I use the string conversions is because there is something weird about the underlying type and using %f or %lf causes weird values to be displayed. I am lazy to figure out why.

Comment: I did some more experimentation and found that `glm::quat(1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0)` works perfectly. I failed to notice that although the guide expresses a quaternion as [x, y, z, w] it states that you initialise it explicitly as `glm::quat(w,x,y,z)`.

Comment: The title of this question is the ideal title. It requires no further reading to understand. It should be upvoted for that property alone.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

A unit quaternion is **NOT the same** as an identity quaternion. A quaternion is just any number in 'quaternion space', like `3 + 2i - 7j + 6k`.

When we are using quaternions to calculate rotations we are always talking about unit quaternions and always have a length of 1, just like a unit vector. Multiplying unit quaternions is a very efficient way of calculating a rotation, but the length must stay the same, 1.

An identity quaternion is a quaternion that doesn't change any quaternion it is multiplied with, thus `1 + 0i + 0j + 0k` or `1`. An identity quaternion is thus a unit quaternion with a rotation of nothing.

Comment: * i, j and k are the x, y and z in glm. w is the 'real' number.

Comment: As per the question, the guide online says "...so this is a unit quaternion, which makes no rotation at all". I think your answer makes a lot of sense, and as per my accepted answer the guide is clearly wrong so I cannot dispute your answer, but it would be nice if you could include an authoritative reference to your definition.

Comment: I don't have my textbooks anymore, but there is a video from 3Blue1Brown that explains it much better anyway.
[https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=d4EgbgTm0Bg](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=d4EgbgTm0Bg)
And a definition on [https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quaternion#Unit_quaternion ](wiki) of a unit quaternion.

Comment: The document "Quaternion Kinematics for the Error-State Kalman Filter" of Joan Solà has a complete and excellent explanation of Quaternions in all its flavours: http://www.iri.upc.edu/people/jsola/JoanSola/objectes/notes/kinematics.pdf

Comment: Revisiting this question, I have accepted this answer instead of mine. However note that the official OpenGL guide states "...so this is a unit quaternion, which makes no rotation at all" and thus according to the guide they are the same thing. That guide really needs rewriting.

Comment: @MarioGarcía. A wonderful reference indeed!

Answer (score 3):

Unit and identity quaternions are the same thing. The guide is badly written and confusing.

`glm::quat q;` does **NOT** create an identity quaternion. It creates an invalid quaternion. The best way to create an identity quaternion is either by `glm::quat q(glm::vec3(0.0, 0.0, 0.0));` or by `glm::quat q(1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0);`. The first generates the quaternion based on a vector of all zero Euler rotations. The second explicitly initialises it to the identity quaternion.

Note that although quaternions are often described as `[x y z w]`, they are stored and initialised as `(w, x, y, z)`.

Comment: they are stored as x,y,z,w

Comment: @Krum, no glm::quat store values as w,x,y,z

Comment: @ravenisadesk not true for recent glm versions: "By default GLM store quaternion components with the x, y, z, w order. GLM_FORCE_QUAT_DATA_WXYZ allows switching the quaternion data storage to the w, x, y, z order." ([GLM manual](https://github.com/g-truc/glm/blob/master/manual.md#section2_21))

Comment: note that you can also use ```glm::identity<glm::quat>()``` to instantiate an identity quaternion.

Comment: I'm not very experienced with OpenGL, but unit and identity quaternions are definitely NOT the same. As @JustNewHere responded, the unit quaternion has a norm equal to 1, while the identity quaternion is 1+0i+0j+0k. You can consider the identity quaternion a subset of the unit quaternion, but not the same.

Comment: Zero is not an invalid quaternion. It's only an invalid versor. 1 is not the only unit quaternion. Any quaternion with norm 1 is a unit or versor.

Comment: That bring said, the guide does indeed seem to be inconsistent at best